# C - SIGALRM blocks getchar()

Tags: c, signals, alarm, getchar

I'm working on a C terminal multiprocess application. The application is menu based, so the user have to choose from the possibilities to do the action. The menu is blocked with a getchar(). Let me show the codepart:

```
do
{
    do
    {
        printf("\n\n---------------\nMenu\n\n");
        printf("1. Option 1\n");
        printf("2. Option 2\n");
        printf("3. Option 3\n");
        printf("4. Exit");
        printf("\n\n---------------\n");

        scanf("%d", &end);

        int c = getchar();

        if(end < 1 || end > 4)
        {
            printf("Try it again!!!\n\n");
        }
    }
    while(end < 1 || end > 4);
}
while(end != 4);
```

So the user need to choose one of the options. But the problem is that the 2nd option needs to kick off a function in every 5 seconds in the background. One of the children will be handled by the function. So I've created an alarm() handler firstly with the simple signal() method. After that I'm realized that the getchar() I/O process is blocked by received signals. I've tried to create a new child which should handle the stdin processes, and send back the result in a pipe for the parent, but this was not worked too.
Let me share the current signal handling part for better understanding:

```
// Alarm handling
void CatchAlarm(int sig)
{
    if(someCounts > 0)
    {
        DoSomething();
        alarm(5);
    }
}
```

Also the alarm binding:

```
struct sigaction alarmAction;
alarmAction.sa_handler = CatchAlarm;
sigemptyset(&alarmAction.sa_mask);
alarmAction.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;
sigaction(SIGALRM, &alarmAction, NULL);
```

My problem is that, I can't send the parent process to sleep, because the user have to be able to do other activities during the alarm is pending. When I get the SIGALRM, the full stdin reading process is going to crazy. Please help me what can I use to block the reading and waiting for user interaction instead of the getchar(), because I've already tried everything. Or if someone can help me how can I solve the issue I can appreciate that.
Of course, if you have further questions or concerns please let me know, and I'm going to update my question as soon as possible.
Thanks in advance

Comment: assuming posix have a look at `select` and `poll`,

Comment: @Jasen  can you describe a little bit, why you've advised that? many thanks

Comment: they're a way to efficiently wait for incoming data on several file handles like your pipe, and STDIN_FILENO. but not on ms-windows.

Comment: regarding triggering the background process:  suggest the background process be the one to catch the alarm, start the alarm, etc. and after doing its' thing, wait/sleep on the alarm.  then the main process starts the back ground process only once.  The main process can remember the process id of the background process and send it a kill signal when the main process is ready to exit

Comment: @MontyX, **man select** and **man poll**  That manual pages explain very well these system calls.

Comment: I don't see any background process.  There is no **fork(2)** in the code so only one process... but I have not seen any **alarm(3)** call in the main code, so if you don't ask the kernel to interrupt you, you'll not be interrupted even the first time.

Comment: My code is much more longer. This is only the questionable part. There is two forked children. There was a 3rd one, when I thought that the alarm signal will affect only this process, but I've learnt that the sigalrm effects somehow the STDIN. So affect all the children and the parent too. So I was not able to separate the effect of the SIGALRM from the getchar(). Of course there is a alarm(5); call prior the menu do-while. The signal handler is only restarting the alarm counting every time.

Answer (score 1):

Just put an `alarm(5);` call before the `getchar();` so the kernel is advised to send a `SIGALRM` signal to interrupt **getchar(3)**.  Then, you don't have to put any code inside the signal handler (but you **do need** the signal handler or the program will be killed, see **alarm(2)** and **kill(2)** for an explanation)  You'll have to uninstall it after the getchar call either case or the signal handler will be called anyway after 5 seconds, but that's left as an exercise for the reader.

### Note on notation

As standard in unix for a long time a reference like **getchar(3)** means the man page for getchar routine that is located in section 3 of the online unix reference manual.  Section 2 is dedicated to system calls and section 3 to library calls historically.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Of course in my code the first alarm sending is prior the first menu do-while, so the 1st getchar(). But this does the same. I also have the signal handler which kick off the DoSomething function.